# random permutation in python2 and torch7

Tags: python, numpy, random, permutation, torch

I've been working with caffe and torch, trying to replicate some experiments when I came across something interesting. It seems that the python `numpy.random.permuation` and `torch.randperm` result in different values when the same seed is used.

python2

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.random.seed(3)
>>> numpy.random.uniform()
0.5507979025745755
>>> numpy.random.seed(3)
>>> numpy.random.permutation(10)
array([5, 4, 1, 2, 9, 6, 7, 0, 3, 8])
>>>
```

torch7

```
th> torch.manualSeed(3)                                      [0.0001s]
th> torch.uniform()
0.55079790437594                                             [0.0002s]
th> torch.manualSeed(3)                                      [0.0001s]
th> torch.randperm(10)
7
1
4
8
9
6
2
10
3
5
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 10]                              [0.0005s]
th>
```

Why are the arrays not the same when providing the same seed?

Comment: There is more than one possible algorithm for producing a random permutation, why would you expect to entirely unrelated packages to use the same one?

Comment: There's no reason to even expect the underlying random number generator to work the same across environments - note that your 0.55 result is not quite the same in both places!  If you must have identical permutations from the same seed, you're going to need to implement the permutation yourself.

Comment: I understand that. I supposed I was looking for the specific reason why they aren't the same (i.e., which algorithm is implemented), then potentially a way to work with each using the same seed -- of course, if that is even possible.